# Verifying TrueType Font 'head' table checksum

Tags: c#, truetype

So I'm reading in a TrueType font file and parsing the tables for various reasons, none of which I'll bore you with here.

I'm currently confused by the 'head' table checksum value; I'm following the spec, setting 'checkSumAdjustment' to 0, calculating the checksum for the entire file and subtracting the result from 0xB1B0AFBA like so:

```
private UInt32 CalculateFileChecksum(EndianBinaryReader reader, UInt32 streamOffset)
{
    var pos = reader.BaseStream.Position; //save current position
    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    UInt32 sum = 0;

    var nLongs = ((reader.BaseStream.Length + 3) & ~3) / 4; //get number of longs (but really uints) to read
    var skipPos = streamOffset + 12; //checksumAdjustment position

    while (nLongs-- > 0)
        if (reader.BaseStream.Position == skipPos)
           reader.BaseStream.Position += 4; //skip the checksumAdjustment value.
        else
            sum += reader.ReadUInt32();

    reader.BaseStream.Position = pos; //restore stream position

    return 0xB1B0AFBA - sum; //as per spec
}
```

My final result from this ALWAYS equals the 'magicNumber' field (1594834165 or 0x5F0F3CF5).

My question is, quite simply:

Is this correct?

If so, can anyone explain how I'm always getting the magic number?

If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `streamOffset + 12` -- offset from where? If it's the start of the `head` table:  According to [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/head.htm], `checkSumAdjustment` is at +8.

Comment: You're completely correct and I'm an idiot! The checksum is now calculating the correct value to match against the checkSumAdjustment field. Thanks!